# Getting -bash: /usr/local/Bluemix/bx/bash_autocomplete: No such file or directory error

Tags: heroku, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

After installing Heroku, I am getting this error

`-bash: /usr/local/Bluemix/bx/bash_autocomplete: No such file or directory`

This only shows up when a start a new terminal

Does anyone know why and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only shows up when you open a window, it's probably because of a line in your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`,`~/.bash_login` is sourcing that file (which doesn't exist), or it's a dependency of heroku-cli & must be installed separately. [Here's](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) a link about which files are called during bash startup.

Also, run `cd /usr/local/` to see if it exists there — if it's not, then reinstall the heroku-cli & pay attention to the output (where such programs will often print instructions regarding which lines you should put in your startup scripts—if they don’t do so automatically)

[Here's a link](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bb/cs348/www-S08/unix_path.html) on how to edit your path, whose directories can be seen by `echo $PATH`. If `/usr/local` isn't, then it should be added.

Comment: I checked my .bash_profile and I didn't see it. These are what I've got PS1="\u$ "
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
alias ll='ls -lahG'
eval "$(rbenv init -)" . I will check .bashrc and .profile. Thank you!

Comment: So I checked the other two and nothing there. I still don't know why. So what I did was to install IBM Cloud CLI. However, I still don't know why it is asking for the package. Something to do with Heroku CLI?

Comment: I downloaded Heroku CLI installer from Heroku's website

Comment: I didn't investigate the issue. Instead, I installed IBM Cloud CLI so it's not showing as missing. I still don't know why it showed up though. I marked you as correct because I think maybe there is something to do with Heroku CLI. Didn't get a chance to inspect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this very problem. If you edit `/etc/profile` you'll see that it contains a reference to Bluemix. Removing that fixes the problem.